# HTML, table between row spacing not the same as within row spacing resulting from br tag

Tags: html

In the example below, where row spacings are allowed to default, when viewed in Firefox the spacing between table rows is different than the spacing within a cell when a BR tag is present.  A bit of experimenting showed that the default spacing is equivalent to

```
  <table cellpadding=1>
```

Changing to cellpadding=0 did not quite resolve the difference - the spacing between rows is still slightly larger than the spacing between parts of a line in a cell separated by BR tags.  Why is this?  (The original html snippet came out of manServer 1.07 and was reduced down to this smaller example.  That is why there are blockquote tags.)  Sticking with html (not html5) how would one make these spacings the same?

```
<HTML>
<BLOCKQUOTE>
<P>
<TABLE cellpadding=0>
<TR>
  <TD><B>-testing_a</B></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
  <TD><B>-testing_b</B></TD>
<TR>
  <TD><B>-testing_c</B><br><B>-testing_d</B><br><B>-testing_e</B></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TR>
  <TD>-testing_2a</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
  <TD>-testing_2b</TD>
<TR>
  <TD>-testing_2c<br>-testing_2d<br>-testing_2e</TD>
</TR>
<TD>
Table line spacing, within cell.
Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
<P>
Paragraph line spacing.
Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
</P>
</BLOCKQUOTE>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out two minutes after posting. Using:

```
<TABLE cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
```

does the trick.  Apparently both of these values default to 1, at least in this browser.